# How to output unicode?

Tags: c#

Hey guys, I need to export data from database which contains Unicode(like Japanese characters). 
While when i trying to export to csv files, it just becomes the garbage....

First, I need to read data from database and save it to an datatable 
Second, I will make a query based on the datatable (Using Linq)
Last, Export the queried results to csv file

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the code you are using for exporting to csv.

Comment: Is it garbage in the file, or is it garbage in the viewer you use for reading the file? Could it be that the file is OK, but the viewer is not showing unicode text?

Answer (score 1):

Internally .Net (C#) always uses unicode. The problems occur when you export the data. Then you need to specify an encoding.

If you use [File.CreateText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx) you immediatly create a UTF-8 encoded file.

Does the application you use for import, recognize the UTF-8 encoding, or does it need a specific encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set connection data collation to unicode_ci or more specidfied.